# How to change TextField's height and width?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield

How to customise `TextField`'s `width` and `height`?

Answer (score 302, accepted):

To adjust the width, you could wrap your `TextField` with a `SizedBox` widget, like so:

```
const SizedBox(
  width: 100.0,
  child: TextField(),
)
```

I'm not really sure what you're after when it comes to the height of the `TextField` but you could definitely have a look at the `TextStyle` widget, with which you can manipulate the `fontSize` and/or `height`

```
const SizedBox(
  width: 100.0,
  child: TextField(
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0, height: 2.0, color: Colors.black),
  ),
)
```

Bear in mind that the `height` in the `TextStyle` is a multiplier of the font size, as per comments on the property itself:

> The height of this text span, as a multiple of the font size.
>
> When [height] is null or omitted, the line height will be determined
> by the font's metrics directly, which may differ from the fontSize.
> When [height] is non-null, the line height of the span of text will be a
> multiple of [fontSize] and be exactly `fontSize * height` logical pixels
> tall.

Last but not least, you might want to have a look at the `decoration` property of you `TextField`, which gives you a lot of possibilities

***EDIT:*** How to change the inner padding/margin of the `TextField`

You could play around with the `InputDecoration` and the `decoration` property of the `TextField`. For instance, you could do something like this:

```
const TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
  ),
)
```

Comment: yes I can update the height/fontSize attributes but there is default padding within the TextField which adds up for extra height & width, how it can be customised .?

Comment: You can use the [`decoration`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_field.dart#L145) property for these purposes. Set it to `null` and all the base styles will be gone.

Comment: Thanks, it complete removes everything. But all i need is to customise the default top and bottom padding/margin within the TextField.

Comment: Please edit your answer again with strike through or something.. It's inconvenient to try the wrong answer, then be surprised that it's edited reading further along the end of it!

Comment: @SamersSalib I'm not sure what are you referring to. Could you be more specific?

Comment: The use of Container, isn't (wasn't) the answer to this question. The edited answer is more appropriate

Comment: Well, OPs question is not very explicit about what exactly he wants to achieve and how w.r.t. height and width of the `TextField`. Only after adding a comment below my answer he mentiones that he's interested in the inner padding of the `TextField`. Therefore I'm not sure if your comment is really valid, as there's many ways to skin a cat and what might be solving your problem might not necessarily solve others.

Comment: Use contentPadding with isDense: True for the best results.`InputDecoration( isDense: true, contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10))`

Comment: Better with SizedBox

Comment: My suggestion is to use `suffixIconConstraints` of `prefixIconConstraints` property

Answer (score 171):

I think you want to change the **inner padding/margin** of the `TextField`.

You can do that by adding `isDense: true` and `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)` properties as follow:

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Default TextField',
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 16,),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Densed TextField',
          isDense: true,                      // Added this
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 16,),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Even Densed TextFiled',
          isDense: true,                      // Added this
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),  // Added this
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

It will be displayed as:

[image: How to update flutter TextField's height and width / Inner Padding?]

Comment: I need the size of the text box increased.  Increasing the 
Container does allow me to see large amounts of inputted data.

Comment: isDense option works for me to reduce the height of the textfield. Thank you @Jay Dhamsaniya

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 65):

### Screenshot:

[image]

---

You can do it in many ways:

- ##### Using `maxLines` + `expands`:

  ```dart
  SizedBox(
    width: 240, // <-- TextField width
    height: 120, // <-- TextField height
    child: TextField(
      maxLines: null,
      expands: true,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      decoration: InputDecoration(filled: true, hintText: 'Enter a message'),
    ),
  )
  ```
- ##### Using just `maxLines`:

  ```dart
  Widget _buildTextField() {
    final maxLines = 5;

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      height: maxLines * 24.0,
      child: TextField(
        maxLines: maxLines,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        decoration: InputDecoration(filled: true, hintText: 'Enter a message'),
      ),
    );
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks. maxLines: maxlines worked.   I can now see large amounts of inputted data.

Comment: yes, this is what i looking for, maxLines worked perfect for my case!

Comment: Not work for me. It's worked after I add "expands: true" into TextField widgets.

Answer (score 20):

This answer works, but it will have conflicts when the input field is in error state, for a better approach and a better control you can use this.

```
InputDecoration(
    isCollapsed: true,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(9),
)
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to increase the height of *TextFormField* **dynamically** while typing the text in it. Set **maxLines** to ***null***. For Example:-

```
TextFormField(
          onSaved: (newText) {
            enteredTextEmail = newText;
          },

          obscureText: false,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          validator: validateName,
          maxLines: null,
          // style: style,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 10.0, 5.0, 10.0),
              hintText: "Enter Question",
              labelText: "Enter Question",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))),
        ),
```

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for !!

Answer (score 12):

Wrap `TextField` in  `SizedBox` for the width

```
SizedBox(
  height: 40,
  width: 150,
  child: TextField(),
)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try the `margin` property in the `Container`. Wrap the `TextField`  inside a `Container` and adjust the `margin` property.

```dart
new Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
  child: new TextField( 
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'username',
      icon: new Icon(Icons.person)),
  )
),
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use "suffixIcon" to collapse the height of the TextField add:
suffixIconConstraints

```
TextField(
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: r * 1.8, color: Colors.black87),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      isDense: true,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: r * 1.6, horizontal: r * 1.6),
                      suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black54),
                      suffixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 32, minHeight: 32),
                    ),
                  )
```

Answer (score 3):

simply wrap the `TextField()` in `SizedBox()` and give the height of the sized box

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Set `minLines: null`, `maxLines: null` and `expands:true` to let the TextField fill the height of its parent widget:

```
Container(
  child: TextField(
    minLines: null,
    maxLines: null,
    expands: true
  )
)
```

Refere to these docs for the same:https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/expands.html

And for width, you can do this:

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  child: TextField(
    
  )
)
```

to let the TextField fill its parent widget's width(100 pixels in this case)

Answer (score 3):

**Adjust Height using contentPadding instead of SizeBox or Container**

```
Container(
        width: width * 0.85,
        child: TextFormField(
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10), //Imp Line
            isDense: true,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  width: 0.5,
                  color: Constants.secondaryColourLight,
                )),
          ),),)
```

`80k ka code hein 80k ka`

Comment: `80k ka code hein 80k ka` I agree...

Answer (score 2):

**use contentPadding, it will reduce the textbox or dropdown list height**

```
InputDecorator(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 16.0),
                      hintText: 'Please select expense',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1.0),
                      ),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),//Add this edge option
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    isDense: true,
                    itemHeight: 50.0,

                    hint: Text(
                        'Please choose a location'), // Not necessary for Option 1
                    value: _selectedLocation,
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedLocation = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                    items: citys.map((location) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: new Text(location.name),
                        value: location.id,
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 2):

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight:48,maxWidth: 327,),
  ),
);
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.

Comment: na dawg skill issue, thanks @DiyorbekDev

Comment: actually what i wanted was minHeight but unfortunately this wont change the height it will add space below your text field, you need to add contentPadding

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got my solution using this trick.

> Provide Height and width of sizedbox and set expand the property to ***true***. Also, set **maxLines to null and minLines to null.**

```
SizedBox(
      height: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.1377,
      child: TextFormField(
        validator: validator,
        enabled: isEnabled,
        expands: true,
        maxLines: null,
        minLines: null,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: setting the expands, the maxLines and the minLines finally made my TextFormField fill my parent SizedBox...ty!

Answer (score 1):

TextField( minLines: 1, maxLines: 5, maxLengthEnforced: true)

Answer (score 1):

```
int numLines = 0;

Container(
     height: numLines < 7 ? 148 * WidgetsConstant.height: numLines * WidgetsConstant.height * 24,
     child: TextFormField(
              controller: _bodyText,
              maxLines: numLines < 7 ? 148 : numLines,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,        
              onChanged: (String value) {
                setState(() {
                  numLines = '\n'.allMatches(value).length + 1;
                });
              },
          ),
     ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The perfect way to get rid of padding is to use `InputDecoration.collapsed`.

It wraps the `GestureDetector` with a `Container` and decorates the Container with as much Padding, Border, and Decoration as needed.

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => _focusNode.requestFocus(),
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.grey,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
    ),
    child: TextField(
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      decoration: const InputDecoration.collapsed(
        hintText: 'Search...',
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 0,
            style: BorderStyle.none,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

To display an icon, change the `Container` child to `Row`, and use `Icon` and a `TextField` wrapped with `Expanded`.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a **maxLines** and add a **BoxConstraints** with **width** and **height** in **InputDecoration**.

```
TextField(
  maxLines: 10,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
    constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 300, height: 100),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just add:**                                     contentPadding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15,horizontal: 15),

Answer (score 1):

i wanted to make the text field a set height and i didnt want to change the max lines field as it should be 1, i achieved this by adding constraints and padding to the input decoration, be careful the error text may mess with the size just make sure to leave enough space

```
return InputDecoration(
  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    vertical: 32,
  ),
  constraints: const BoxConstraints(
    maxHeight: 72,
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

To increase the height of TextField Widget just make use of the maxLines: properties that comes with the widget. For Example:
TextField(
maxLines: 5
) // it will increase the height and width of the Textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap Text field widget in padding widget.....
Like this,

```
Padding(
         padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
          child: TextField(
            cursorColor: Colors.blue,

            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Email',
                hintText: 'xyz@gmail.com',
                //labelStyle: textStyle,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.blue,)),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.green)),
                )

            ),
          ),
```

Comment: typically you would use SizedBox

Answer (score 0):

You can change max

```
minLines: 4,
maxLines: 6,
```

Answer (score 0):

For height, you can simply use `maxLines`.