# FormField is ignoring parent container size

Tags: flutter

I have a [`DateTimeFormField`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_formfield) who's `InkWell` height is way too much. I tried controlling it by putting a `Container` with a fixed height above it but it didn't seem to do anything. I also tried it with a `SizedBox` and still nothing. I do use a `GridView.count` to build the fields side-by-side.

Here's my setup:

```
Expanded(
  child: GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    primary: false,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: formBloc.startEndTimeFields.map((field) {
      return BlocBuilder(
        bloc: field,
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Container(
            height: 100,
            child: DateTimeFormField(
              formatter: DateFormat("HH:mm a"),
              onlyTime: true,
              label: "",
              initialValue: DateTime.now(),
              onSaved: (value) {
                field.updateValue(value);
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
),
```

I have a picture with the `InkWell` clicked on to show you what it looks like.

[image: picture]

Comment: May be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400529/how-to-update-flutter-textfields-height-and-width

Comment: It's from a package, I can't change the source. @Pavel

Comment: Do you mean `flutter_datetime_formfield` package? It's has just 130 lines of code: https://github.com/jczhong/flutter_datetime_formfield/tree/master/lib Fork/copy and modify it