# Failed assertion: line 549 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I am new to Flutter. I am using bottom  navigation view . At the **Dashboard** class , there is the bottomnavigaton. The first of bottom navigation is **Home** class which have the tab view. The first page of the tabview is the **NewRequest** class. When the application is first run, the first page of the tab view is not loaded but when going in other class and come back to the **Home**, the **New Request** is loaded. How to load the tabview first page when the app is first run? I have implemented as follows:

```
class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget{

@override
 State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
   return _DashboardState();
 }

}
 class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard>{

int _currentIndex=0;
bool home=true;
final tabs=[
 Home(),
 Center(child: Text('History')),
 Center(child: Text('Wallet')),
   Center(child: Text('More')),
  ];

 final _title=[
  Center(child: Text("Dashboard"),),
  Center(child:Text("History"),),
  Center(child:Text("Wallet"),),
  Center(child:Text("More"),),];


  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: home ? null :AppBar(
         title: _title[_currentIndex],
         automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    ),
    body: Container(
    child: tabs[_currentIndex],
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(),
);
}

Widget _bottomNavigationBar(){
 return BottomNavigationBar(
    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: Text("Home"),          
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.history),
        title: Text("History"),  
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),
        title: Text("Wallet"), 
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
        title: Text("More"),
      )
    ],
    onTap: (index){
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex=index;
        if (index==0) {
          home=true;
        }else{
          home=false;
        }
      });
    },
  ) ;
 }
}
```

My Home page

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
   State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomeState();
   }
}

 class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int index;
  @override
void initState() {
super.initState();
index = 0;
}

final pages = [
NewRequest(),
new Column(
  children: <Widget>[new Text("Accepted Page")],
),
new Column(
  children: <Widget>[new Text("Cooking Page")],
),
new Column(
  children: <Widget>[new Text("Cooked Page")],
)
];

final tabs = [
Text('Request'),
Text('Accepted'),
Text('Cooking'),
Text('Cooked'),
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: new DefaultTabController(
    length: 4,
    initialIndex: 0,
    child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(56.0),
          child: new Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: new SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(
                    child: new Container(
                        child: new TabBar(
                      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                      labelColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      isScrollable: true,
                      tabs: List<Widget>.generate(4, (index) {
                        return tabs[index];
                      }),
                    )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            NewRequest(),
            new Column(
              children: <Widget>[new Text("Accepted Page")],
            ),
            new Column(
              children: <Widget>[new Text("Cooking Page")],
            ),
            new Column(
              children: <Widget>[new Text("Cooked Page")],
            )
          ],
        )),
  ),
);
}
```

New Request page

```
class NewRequest extends StatelessWidget{

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: <Widget>[_CardView(), _CardView(), _CardView(), _CardView()],
  );    
 }  
}

 Widget _CardView() {
  return Card(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
    elevation: 15.0,
    child: Container(
      height: 185,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: FittedBox(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/momo.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  child: Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("Momo", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0))
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Rs.100",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "2 Plate",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )))
            ],
          ),
          Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 5.0, right: 5.0, top: 5.0, bottom: 2.0),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text(
                      "Reject",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => null,
                  ),
                )),
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 5.0, right: 5.0, top: 5.0, bottom: 0.0),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text(
                      "Approve",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => null,
                  ),
                )),
              ])
        ],
      ),
    ));
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

This is late but I've just had the same issue. I'm not sure how to solve your specific example but I'm posting my solution to my problem here in hopes that it might help someone else.

```
return Row(children: [
    Container(child: Text('•'), margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25*indentLevel.toDouble(), right: 5),),
    Expanded(child: TextField(
      cursorColor: Colors.black,
      autofocus: true,
    ))
  ]);
```

My problem was with the `TextField` - Failed assertion: ... 'hasSize.'
The TextField doesn't have an explicit size option and instead inherits from its parent. (assumed from this post on [sizing a TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400529/how-to-update-flutter-textfields-height-and-width) using a container.) If the parent also doesn't have a specific size (ex. Row, Column, ListView vertically) then errors can occur. As you can see in my code above, **I was able to fix** this issue by wrapping the `TextField` in an expanded Widget, which fills its parent to get its own dimensions which it in turn passes down to the `TextField`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was adding the Expanded widget to an element of the listView
so I removed it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Widget which is throwing error can be wrapped in a Container with a Specified height. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Nbn try removing the isScrollable property in the TabBar widget of the My Home Page file.