# Horizontal scroll in TextFormField flutter on text input

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an email input text field when I write more text than the width of this input, the rest of the text is not visible. Is there a way to have a horizontal scroll as I input into this text form field?

The following image describes the behavior I want.

[image: HorizontalScroll in TextFormField]

**Edit**: My Code

```dart
Container(
  width: 270,
  height: 42,
  child: new TextFormField(
    validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.email_outlined,
      ),
      labelText: 'Email',
      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
        borderSide: new BorderSide(),
      ),
    ),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    onChanged: (val) {
      setState(() => email = val);
    },
  ),
),
```

This is what happens when I type beyond the width of the TextFormField
[image: This is what happens when I type beyond the width of the TextFormField]

Comment: What type of output you are getting? Because the thing you want to achieve is the default behavior of `TextFormField()` and if you want to see hidden content you can scroll to the right to see the content you previously typed.

Comment: So when I start typing beyond the width, the text is no longer visible.

Comment: Can you somehow show it ?

Comment: Sure i'll add a few images

Comment: Remove your height attribute from your `Container()` it is causing problem

Comment: And if you want to change padding inside your `TextFormField()` change contentPadding inside `InputDecoration()`.

Comment: @ChiragBargoojar I removed the height attribute for the container, but I would still like the TextFormField to have a height of 42, is this possible?

Comment: Check this answer you will know why you don't want to give your `TextField()` a hardcoded height. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50402596/11855654

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this:

1. You can add the isDense property to your TextFormField, in which case your code will look like this:

```dart
Container(
        width: 270,
        height: 42,
        child: TextFormField(
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
          validator: (val) => val!.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            isDense: true,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.email_outlined,
            ),
            labelText: 'Email',
            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              borderSide: new BorderSide(),
            ),
          ),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() => email = val);
          },
        ),
      ),
```

This fixes the problem to an extent, however if font that extends lower(like commas, semicolons etc. still get clipped off). The next method fixes this:

2. Use the contentPadding property, since if you check the source code, all isDense does is modify the contentPadding property's value. This is some of the actual code behind isDense:

```dart
if (decoration!.filled == true) { // filled == null same as filled == false
        contentPadding = decorationContentPadding ?? (decorationIsDense
          ? const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 8.0, 12.0, 8.0)
          : const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0));
      } else {
        // Not left or right padding for underline borders that aren't filled
        // is a small concession to backwards compatibility. This eliminates
        // the most noticeable layout change introduced by #13734.
        contentPadding = decorationContentPadding ?? (decorationIsDense
          ? const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 8.0)
          : const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 12.0));
      }
```

As you can see, all Flutter does behind the scenes is assign hardcoded values to your arguments based on the parameters you've passed. In your case, the best configuration seems to be:

```dart
Container(
        width: 270,
        height: 42,
        child: TextFormField(
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
          validator: (val) => val!.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 8.0, 12.0, 8.0),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.email_outlined,
            ),
            labelText: 'Email',
            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              borderSide: new BorderSide(),
            ),
          ),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() => email = val);
          },
        ),
      ),
```

The above code fixes your issue, but might create more problems if your font height changes.